# Laravel 5 make a custom register function

Tags: php, laravel, registration, laravel-5.1

Laravel 5 has it's default register function which is in

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

I know that I can copy this code and paste it in my `AuthController` but there's a change that I need to make which I don't know where to start and find. What I want is change the code for the insertion of data in my `users` table. I want to change this because I add another column in my `users` table which is `company_name` and I have a table which is named `companies` so basically when the user enter a `company_name` for registration it will check the `companies` table if it is existing then return error message if it is. So think there is something like:

```
$rules = array(
        'company_name' => 'unqiue:companies',

    );
```

But i don't know where to put this thing in my registration code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom validation, in this case. **Make sure, you a are calling `$this->validate()`, and not `$this->validator`.** This validate will automatically redirect back with errors if it fails, so you can skip the check statement.

```php
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request->all(), [
        'company_name' => 'unique:companies',
        // And the other rules, like email unqiue, etc..
    ]);  

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `company_name` as fillable, in your user model.